# Какой размер экрана выставлять в медиа запросе под телефоны?

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, media-queries, адаптивность

Здравствуйте, какой самый оптимальный размер в медиазапросах под телефоны?

Comment: Та, при которой начинает ехать разметка для более крупных.

Answer (score 1):

Extra small devices **Phones** (<768px)

Small devices **Tablets** (≥768px)

Medium devices **Desktops** (≥992px)

Large devices **Desktops** (≥1200px)

У bootstrap собственно такие, считаю их оптимальными.

Comment: Спорно, горизонтальный айпад посчитается десктопом, а для горизонтального айфона дизайн, сделанный для вертикального айфона, может не подойти